# How to prevent SIGPIPE in sendfile function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, signals

Good day i have small http server where i have threadpool current connections, when i do send file in thread i get signal SIGPIPE and my server crash. Part of code: 
//in thread:

```
 detail::create_headers(headers,stat_buf.st_size,mime_types::extension_to_type(extension.c_str()));
    if(detail::write_to_client(fd_client,headers,unicode_strlen(headers))!=-1)
    {
        while(offset!=stat_buf.st_size)
        {
            if(sendfile(fd_client,src,&offset,stat_buf.st_size)==-1)
            {
                DEBUG_MSG_FORMAT("sendfile error: %d",errno);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

//and :

```
size_t write_to_client(int fd_client,const void *buf,size_t len)
{
    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt (fd_client, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, &optval, sizeof (int));
    size_t result = write(fd_client,buf,len);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        DEBUG_MSG_FORMAT("write error: %d",errno);
    }
    optval = 0;
    setsockopt (fd_client, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, &optval, sizeof (int));
                return result;
}
```

How can i handle or prevent SIGPIPE in thread?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i handle or prevent SIGPIPE in thread?

At least three ways:

- Use the `SO_NOSIGPIPE` socket option
- Use the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag for `send(2)` (Linux-specific)
- Ignore the sigpipe (using `SIG_IGN`) or establish a real handler for it

I would go for the first one if possible (it's not portable). Instead of the signal you'll get a return of -1 with `errno = EPIPE`.

Comment: You can also write an interceptor for that signal.

Comment: @DariuszWawer Good call :-)

Comment: I want to use signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); but it is not working at all.

Comment: You probably have to put the signal() call on the correct thread; I am pretty sure, that all newly created threads require either signal setup through pthread options befor ecreation, or standard setup using signal() after it is created.

Comment: May new c++11 standart thread affected to solution, and where needed write "signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, `sendfile()` does not have any flags (like e.g. `send()` does with `MSG_NOSIGNAL`), so one option is to disable SIGPIPE using `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`, but that does not keep debuggers like `gdb` to stop your process on `SIGPIPE`. If you want `gdb` to keep your code running, try `handle SIGPIPE nostop` in `gdb` or replace `sendfile()` by a `read/send` loop with `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flags.